# Nested list in component from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I'm searching for a little help/advice. I had a task to create a multiple nested list from array of object. I did this, got a expected result, but the problem was my code was very complicated and not clean for sure, because i did it by mapping, filtering, and again mapping, mapped arrays. This give me a lot of code, and i am pretty sure you can do it a lot of easier, that's why i am searching for help. I am using react(18.2.0), but even good methods for situations like that in vanilla js will be very helpful for me.

So I have a JSON file with a lot of data, I give a example because there is like Array[500+] object inside.

```
"data": [
        {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "name": "Football",
            "lvl": 1,
            "parent": 0,
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "name": "Basketball",
            "lvl": 1,
            "parent": 0,
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 3,
            "name": "Bundesliga",
            "lvl": 2,
            "parent": 1,
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 4,
            "name": "NBA",
            "lvl": 2,
            "parent": 2,
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 5,
            "name": "Wizards",
            "lvl": 3,
            "parent": 4,
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 6,
            "name": "Lakers",
            "lvl": 3,
            "parent": 4,
        },

.....and more
```

If parent === categoryId it means that it's children.

So the result component should give something like that:

```
 - Football
      - Bundesliga
    - Basketball
      - NBA
        - Wizards
        - Lakers
```

I will be happy if you give me some good practices, advice about situations like that. Should I use recursion or what? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to write this recursively, you could write it something like this:

```
const recursive = function(data, node, current, max) {
  if(current > max) {
    return {};
  }
  data.forEach( d => {
    if(!node.children) {
      node.children = [];
    }
    if(d.lvl === current && (d.parent === node.categoryId || current === 1)) {
      node.children.push(d);
      recursive(data, d, current+1, max)
    }
  });
}

let newObj = {};
let highestLevel = 1;
data.forEach(d => {
  if(d.lvl > highestLevel) {
    highestLevel = d.lvl;
  }
})
recursive(data, newObj, 1, highestLevel)
```

I wrote this in `playcode.io` so that you can see it working: https://playcode.io/926085

The output is the entire objects, nested. But you can then print just the names from the resulting nested structure.

I don't think that this solution is the most optimal one, as far as time complexity goes. But it's a recursive example of how to solve the problem.

I'm open to someone optimizing this solution, as I am also interested in this problem.

**UPDATE**

I had a friend work on a solution. He optimized so that I think its O(n): https://playcode.io/926145/

```
const f = (input, map = {}) => {
  input.forEach(d => {
    const me = map[d.categoryId]

    if(!me) {
      map = {...map, [d.categoryId]: [] }
    }

    const siblings = map[d.parent]
    if(siblings) {
      map = {...map, [d.parent]: [...siblings, d]}
    } else {
      map = {...map, [d.parent]: [d]}
    }
  })

  return map
}

const print = (map, input, toPrint, indent = 0) => {
  toPrint.forEach(p => {
    const ind = " ".repeat(indent)

    console.log(`${ind} - ${p.name}`)

    print(map, input, map[p.categoryId], indent + 2)
  })
}

const map = f(data.data)
print(map, data.data, map[0])
```